# Access the RGB camera (or Locatable Camera) at 30fps on HoloLens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to access the Hololens locatable camera at 30 FPS at minimum possible latency. I have tried using `WebCamTexture` but it has a significant latency along with the frame Drop. I also used the `MediaCapture` example(which seems to be significantly faster) but it displays on a 2D element `CaptureElemnet`. Is there any way to get a byte array of each frame using MediaCapture API so that I can render it on cube texture in Unity3D.

Comment: I assume you have taken a look at this? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/locatable_camera

Comment: Yes But I coudn't find any help with this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We made an open source project called [CameraStream](https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream) to address this need. As a Unity plugin, it uses MediaCapture to feed the byte array into Unity (along with locatable matrices). From there you can assign the bytes to a `Texture2D`, as shown in the provided Unity example.

Comment: It is giving 30FPS but latency is still there and I guess it is because `Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData` takes too much time. I'll try to fix this with Opengl plugin.

Comment: Is your project using Vuforia at all? (I haven't open it yet)

Comment: @KansaiRobot No, I haven't tried integrating the two together. Vuforia has a proprietary implementation for obtaining the camera stream (probably very similar to my project), but the two libraries might fight over getting handles to the camera feed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand. I asked because I wanted to know before checking your project.

Comment: I tried your project and it is quite awesome. However as others have noticed the video is shown inverted. I read that a shader can solve that.